How to handle client-side validation with AES-GCM encrypted cookies?
Currently, I am trying to find a way to keep users on my site logged in and redirect them to the login page if they are not. I am using React + Tsx and React Router Dom for my frontend, and a Golang http server using the standard libraries net/http package.
I have two routes for cookies, a get cookie route and set cookie router. I essentially just copy and paste the code provided by this article until the encryption part.
Here is the code for the routes:
func Write(w http.ResponseWriter, cookie http.Cookie) error {
    // Encode the cookie value using base64.
    cookie.Value = base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(cookie.Value))

    // Check the total length of the cookie contents. Return the ErrValueTooLong
    // error if it's more than 4096 bytes.
    if len(cookie.String()) > 4096 {
        return ErrValueTooLong
    }

    // Write the cookie as normal.
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

    return nil
}

func Read(r *http.Request, name string) (string, error) {
    // Read the cookie as normal.
    cookie, err := r.Cookie(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Decode the base64-encoded cookie value. If the cookie didn't contain a
    // valid base64-encoded value, this operation will fail, and we return an
    // ErrInvalidValue error.
    value, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(cookie.Value)
    if err != nil {
        return "", ErrInvalidValue
    }

    // Return the decoded cookie value.
    return string(value), nil
}

func WriteEncrypted(w http.ResponseWriter, cookie http.Cookie, secretKey []byte) error {
    // Create a new AES cipher block from the secret key.
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(secretKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Wrap the cipher block in Galois Counter Mode.
    aesGCM, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create a unique nonce containing 12 random bytes.
    nonce := make([]byte, aesGCM.NonceSize())
    _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Prepare the plaintext input for encryption. Because we want to
    // authenticate the cookie name as well as the value, we make this plaintext
    // in the format "{cookie name}:{cookie value}". We use the : character as a
    // separator because it is an invalid character for cookie names and
    // therefore shouldn't appear in them.
    plaintext := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", cookie.Name, cookie.Value)

    // Encrypt the data using aesGCM.Seal(). By passing the nonce as the first
    // parameter, the encrypted data will be appended to the nonce — meaning
    // that the returned encryptedValue variable will be in the format
    // "{nonce}{encrypted plaintext data}".
    encryptedValue := aesGCM.Seal(nonce, nonce, []byte(plaintext), nil)

    // Set the cookie value to the encryptedValue.
    cookie.Value = string(encryptedValue)

    // Write the cookie as normal.
    return Write(w, cookie)
}

func ReadEncrypted(r *http.Request, name string, secretKey []byte) (string, error) {
    // Read the encrypted value from the cookie as normal.
    encryptedValue, err := Read(r, name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Create a new AES cipher block from the secret key.
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(secretKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Wrap the cipher block in Galois Counter Mode.
    aesGCM, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Get the nonce size.
    nonceSize := aesGCM.NonceSize()

    // To avoid a potential 'index out of range' panic in the next step, we
    // check that the length of the encrypted value is at least the nonce
    // size.
    if len(encryptedValue) < nonceSize {
        return "", ErrInvalidValue
    }

    // Split apart the nonce from the actual encrypted data.
    nonce := encryptedValue[:nonceSize]
    ciphertext := encryptedValue[nonceSize:]

    // Use aesGCM.Open() to decrypt and authenticate the data. If this fails,
    // return a ErrInvalidValue error.
    plaintext, err := aesGCM.Open(nil, []byte(nonce), []byte(ciphertext), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return "", ErrInvalidValue
    }

    // The plaintext value is in the format "{cookie name}:{cookie value}". We
    // use strings.Cut() to split it on the first ":" character.
    expectedName, value, ok := strings.Cut(string(plaintext), ":")
    if !ok {
        return "", ErrInvalidValue
    }

    // Check that the cookie name is the expected one and hasn't been changed.
    if expectedName != name {
        return "", ErrInvalidValue
    }

    // Return the plaintext cookie value.
    return value, nil
}

// Route Code
func setSessionCookieHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    enableCors(&w, true)
    // This value is for readability for max age. Max Age uses seconds to represent its expiration time
    hours := 3600

    // Write the cookie. If there is an error (due to an encoding failure or it
    // being too long) then log the error and send a 500 Internal Server Error
    // response.
    bytesCount, byteCountErr := getByteLength()
    if byteCountErr != nil {
        log.Println(byteCountErr)
        http.Error(w, "byte retrieval error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    randString, randStringErr := GenerateRandomString(bytesCount)
    if randStringErr != nil {
        log.Println(randStringErr)
        http.Error(w, "random string generation error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    cookie := http.Cookie{
        Name:   <name of cookie>,
        Value:  randString,
        Path:   "/",
        MaxAge: hours * 2,
        // Set back to true
        HttpOnly: false,
        Secure:   true,
        SameSite: http.SameSiteLaxMode,
    }

    bytes, bytesErr := hex.DecodeString(os.Getenv("AESBLOCKBYTESTRING"))
    if bytesErr != nil {
        log.Println(bytesErr)
        http.Error(w, "byte generation error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    err := WriteEncrypted(w, cookie, bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // Write a HTTP response as normal.
    w.Write([]byte("cookie set!"))
}

func getSessionCookieHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    enableCors(&w, true)

    bytes, bytesErr := hex.DecodeString(os.Getenv("AESBLOCKBYTESTRING"))
    if bytesErr != nil {
        log.Println(bytesErr)
        http.Error(w, "byte generation error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    value, err := ReadEncrypted(r, "id", bytes)
    if err != nil {
        switch {
        case errors.Is(err, http.ErrNoCookie):
            http.Error(w, "cookie not found", http.StatusBadRequest)
        case errors.Is(err, ErrInvalidValue):
            http.Error(w, "invalid cookie", http.StatusBadRequest)
        default:
            log.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, "server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte(value))
}

(The enable cors code I don't think is relevant as I am able to get requests from the server and back, and it isn't the main issue of this post)
For my frontend code I have something like this:
export const FooComponent = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    checkSessionCookies().then((value) => setLoginStatus(value));
  }, [setLoginStatus]);
  return (
    <div>{isLoggedIn ? <h1>Is Logged In</h1> : <Navigate to={"/login"} />}</div>
  );
};

export async function checkSessionCookies(): Promise<boolean> {
  return getCookie("id") === (await getCookieFromApi());
}

// I found this function online. I forget where.
export function getCookie(name: string): string | null {
  const nameLenPlus = name.length + 1;
  return (
    document.cookie
      .split(";")
      .map((c) => c.trim())
      .filter((cookie) => {
        return cookie.substring(0, nameLenPlus) === `${name}=`;
      })
      .map((cookie) => {
        return decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(nameLenPlus));
      })[0] || null
  );
}

export async function getCookieFromApi(): Promise<string> {
  return axios
    .get(<api route for getting the cookie>, {
      withCredentials: true,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    });
}


The set-cookie request gets sent onClick for the login button, and it works normally, as I am able to view it from inspecting the page.
This is what I have tried so far, but I realized the value retrieved by the set cookie route is encrypted while the value retrieved by the get cookie route is decrypted.
Either I decrypt the stored cookie or encrypt the retrieved cookie from the get cookie route on the client side.
If I encrypt the password, the string value would be randomized I believe from the algorithmn.
I tried implementing a decryption function on the client using the buffer library and the cryptoJs library:
function decrypt_AES_GCM(cookie: string): string {
  const decode = (str: string): string =>
    Buffer.from(str, "base64").toString("binary");

  let decodedBase64Cookie = decode(cookie);
  console.log(decodedBase64Cookie);

  let decrypted = AES.decrypt(
    decodedBase64Cookie,
    import.meta.env.VITE_AESSECRETKEY,
    {
      mode: mode.CBC,
    }
  );

  return decrypted.toString(enc.Utf8);
}

This function keeps on returning an empty string so I am not sure what the issue could be. Would anyone know what is wrong with the decryption function and is there a better way to do cookie validation? Thank you in advance for any help. If a need for more of my code to be provided, I would be happy to do so (as long as it is not sensitive information obviously).

Can you please clarify your goal. If the client has the key (needed to decrypt/encrypt the cookie) then you must assume the end user also has the key (and can forge your cookie, as GCM is Symmetric-key). Generally an auth cookie will be set to HttpOnly (as shown in the example you are using) which will make it inaccessible to javascript in the browser. If you just want the front end to be able to detect if a user is probably logged on, then you can use local storage, or a separate cookie, to act as a flag.

I am trying to verify a user is logged in. How does the end user have the key and why do you say probably logged on? If I were to use local storage, then I would have the manage the expiration time of the cookie, and I would still need to do the verification, right?

decrypt_AES_GCM needs the key, so the client would need the key, you should assume that anything you send to the client is accessible by the end user (you have no control over the client). You could use an asymmetric algorithm, but I don't think that's needed here. I said probably because things may change on the server side (say the user changes their password and you invalidate other sessions, the client cannot know this until it communicates with the server). Simplest approach is probably two cookies with the same expiry, one HttpOnly and one to indicate the session is active.

The key is in an env variable so I am not sure how the end user would get that information. When you mean have two cookies, do you mean something like this:
return ( 
<div>
{isLoggedIn ? <h1>Is Logged In</h1> : <Navigate to={"/login"} />
 </div>
  );```
? 
If so, what would be the purpose of the HttpOnly cookie?

See the vite docs "which are statically replaced at build time" - the key will be in the JavaScript sent to the client (think this through, the function needs the key to work, so how could it run on the client without the key?). Ref your example - correct. The HttpOnly cookie contains whatever your server needs to confirm a session is active (session ID, JWT etc); you could just use one cookie (with the client checking if that exists) but protecting your token in an HttpOnly cookie makes it harder for malicious JS to steal it.

Thank you for the help. Sorry for all the questions, but couldn't a malicious user just steal the non HttpOnly cookie and do some type of attack?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
